# Visual Studio Code: Invoke intelliSense in object

Tags: visual-studio-code

In Visual Studio Community Edition when you press:

```
control + j
```

It brings up the intelisense for that object, showing it's members.

What is the equivalent of that for Visual Studio Code ?

Answer (score 1):

According to [the docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense), the answer is <kbd>ctrl + space</kbd>. I have just now confirmed that this is the case, as well.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work exactly like Visual Studio Community Edition.  When you press control + space on a member of an object it triggers intelisense but it doesn't show all the members, it filters it to that member you are on which is not helpful.  Any way to get a full list ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking for here. What is your use case for showing members that don't relate to the thing you are currently on?

Comment: Well, your probably not thinking of this case: Say you have an object that has 10 members.  And you are on the following line:  Object.DoSomthing().  Now in VS Code if you do ctrl + space when your on DoSomething the intelisense only shows DoSomething.  In contrast to VS Community Edition, the intelisense will show all the members but will select the one your on. See how VS Code is no help but VS Community Edition is super helpful ?

Comment: But what is the end goal that you're trying to accomplish? Do you want to replace `DoSomething` inline? Do you want to write a new line of code? What is your use case?

Comment: Well, I thought it was obvious that I want to select a new member from the object I'm on.

Comment: Select a new member for inline replacement, or for writing a new line of code?

Comment: Just for inline replacement :), I'm not sure I understand the new line of code case right now (probably we are not on the same page).

Comment: Well, you could <kbd>⌘D</kbd> to select the element you're on, then delete it and hit <kbd>^ space</kbd>. You must see more reuse out of this particular task than me.

Comment: I use it all the time as I'm actively working on a project, deleting is what I'm trying to find a work around for to reduce some steps - since the alternative so much simpler.